# awk: print columns based on values of another column

Tags: printing, awk

I have a file with six columns, and I only want to print the first two columns of the lines that have a value >3 in the sixth column.

This statement prints all lines where the sixth column > 3

```
awk '$6 > 3' file > out
```

This statement prints the first two columns:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' file > out
```

Anyone knows how to combine these two commands into a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are almost there,just as you said, "combine them"! .  try this:

```
awk '$6>3{print $1,$2}' file >out
```

Comment: Did not expect it to be that easy... Thanks!!