# awk: extracting columns based on column values

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

I have a file that looks somewhat like this:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

but much larger...

I want to extract only the columns that have all 0's in them, so my output file should look like this:

```
C1 C3 C5
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Can this be done with a simple awk one-liner (similar to [awk: print columns based on values of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160241/awk-print-columns-based-on-values-of-another-column) for example)? If no, is there another way to do this effectively using bash?

Comment: How much larger is much larger?  Does your file fit comfortably in ram?

Comment: Yes, not that much larger. A couple of thousand lines, and between 50 & 100 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for data with negative number or other strings like '`foo`' or '`bar`'

one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==1{next}NR==FNR{while(++i<=NF)if($i!="0")k[i];i=0;next}{while(++x<=NF)if(!(x in k))printf "%s ",$x;x=0;print ""}' file file
```

more readable:

```
awk 'NR==1{next}
     NR==FNR{while(++i<=NF)if($i!="0")k[i];i=0;next}
     {while(++x<=NF)
         if(!(x in k)) printf "%s ",$x
      x=0
      print ""}' file file
```

Answer (score 4):

Try following `awk`

```
awk 'NR==1 {next} NR==FNR { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i; next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (sum[i]==0) printf " %s", $i; print "" }' file{,}
```

Output

```
 C1 C3 C5
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
 0 0 0
```

Idea here is to iterated of *file* twice. Once it calculates sum of all columns and in next iteration it prints only columns having sum equal to zero.

This assumes all column entries have *positive numbers only*

---

Another, may be *better*, approach would be to set a flag if any entry in a column is non-zero. And then print only those columns for which correspondig flag is zero.

```
awk 'NR==1 {next} NR==FNR { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i) flag[i]=1; next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!flag[i]) printf " %s", $i; print "" }' file{,}
```

This approach allows positive as well as negative numbers and removes any restriction.

Or as suggested by *@fedorqui* in a comment

```
awk 'NR==1 {next} NR==FNR { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i) flag[i]=1; next } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (flag[i]) $i="" } 1' file{,}
```

Comment: +1 for the way of thinking it. Maybe you can use `{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (flag[i]) $i=""}1` for the second block: just empty the columns with flag and then add `1` (or Kent's 7 :D) to make it print the line.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for your suggestion. That also works but I would call it workaround to make column null rather than deleting it. It introduces extra set of spaces between columns. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it introduces extra spaces between the columns. But the original approach (talking about the second solution suggested in the answer) doesn't seem to give me back columns in the output file... I can see from the header that the right columns were extracted, but it does not start a new line when it should (it gives the entire output in one line)...  Any idea why?

Comment: @Jotne Can you please check if your `ORS` is set properly to `\n`. It should have that value by default

Comment: Who do I do that? I do not see you have set it on your solution, and it does not help to set it with `ORS="\n"`.  I do not see how your solution would give a new line, you do not  print "" nor printf "\n"

Comment: @Jotne Oops. Sorry! I had tested it in Windows and had `\r` in last column, which was taking it to new line. My bad. Updated ans with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Abdel I have updated ans with suggestions of Jotne and  fedorqui

Answer (score 1):

A loooong solution.
Convert column to row

```
awk '{
       for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) { a[NR, f] = $f }
     }
     NF > nf { nf = NF }
     END {
       for (f = 1; f <= nf; f++) {
           for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++) {
               printf a[r, f] (r==NR ? RS : FS)
           }
       }
    }' file >tmp1
```

Print only rows with only `0`

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) f+=$i} !f; {f=0}' tmp1 >tmp2
```

Convert back

```
awk '{
       for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) { a[NR, f] = $f }
     }
     NF > nf { nf = NF }
     END {
       for (f = 1; f <= nf; f++) {
           for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++) {
               printf a[r, f] (r==NR ? RS : FS)
           }
       }
    }' tmp2
```

Gives

```
C1 C3 C5
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```