# awk: print one column or another depending on the value of another column

Tags: awk, gawk

The input to awk has multiple columns. 
I would like to print column $x or column $y depending on the value of column $z.

For example:
The input is

```
3 2 1
4 5 6
```

I want to print first column if the third column is 1 and print second column otherwise.

Output should be

```
3
5
```

Comment: Similar questions are [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160241/awk-print-columns-based-on-values-of-another-column) and [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739057/awk-print-column-3-if-2-a-specific-value). But they print or do not print one column. I would like to print  a different column depending on the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First some test data:

```
$ cat > file
1 2 2
1 2 1
```

Using conditional operator:

```
$ awk '{print ($3==1?$1:$2)}' file
2
1
```

If the value of the third field is 1, output the value of the first field, else the second field value.

Answer (score 0):

Using [if-else](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#If-Statement) statement in the pattern

```
awk '{if($3 == 1) {x = 1} else {x = 2}; {print $x}}'
```